# Intermittent Network Performance Problems

Tags: vlan, arp, performance, netgear-prosafe

I've been dealing with an intermittent issue in my network for several weeks now.

Symptoms:

1. Periodic "Destination host unreachable.", and similar errors when pinging.  The following is indicative:
   Pinging 10.0.64.16 with 32 bytes of data:
   Reply from 172.31.0.18: Destination host unreachable.
   Reply from 172.31.0.18: Destination host unreachable.
   Reply from 10.0.64.16: bytes=32 time=1004ms TTL=62
   Reply from 10.0.64.16: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=62
2. Our JavaEE server periodically looses connection to our SQL Server (Microsoft).
3. An internal piece of software written on Microsoft Access, and backed by the SQL Server, periodically experience significant performance degradation.
4. Our virtual machines experience periodic latency spikes when accessing their storage, over iSCSI.
5. Various latency sensitive tools get disconnected (SSH, XenCenter), while latency insensitive tools experience no issues (web based dashboards).

Oddly enough, it doesn't appear that we experience all of the above at the same time, it's more like a rolling issue.

We have a Netgear XS728T at the core of our network.  It handles inter-VLAN routing.
We have 3 racks, each of which has a stack of 2 Netgear S3300 switches, which connect to the XS728T using LCAP enabled LAGs of 10G.

Users connect through stacks of Netgear S3300 switches, connected to the core using LACP enabled LAGs of 10G.

We have tried enabling Flow Control between the stacks at the top of the racks and the core.  When we enabled this, we did start seeing pause frames being exchanged, but the situation didn't appear to improve.

We have tried doubling the number of 10G links in the connections between the rack stacks and the core (from 2x10G to 4x10G).  This also didn't appear to improve the situation.

We have been reviewing the switch logs regularly, and are not seeing anything out of the ordinary.

The network is free of loops, except in the stacking, STP is disabled.  We enabled it briefly, and it did not disable any links.

I feel like we have one or more switches with an MAC table issue.

Any suggestions on ways to collect additional information?  Any troubleshooting suggestions?

Thank you,

Dominic Hilsbos

Comment: If it's a ARP cache issue, it will be on the XS728T.  Turn STP back on and leave it on.  It's good protection.  It's conceivable that you have an intermittent STP loop.

Comment: Layer-2 switches do not use ARP, only layer-3 devices, e.g. routers and hosts, use ARP.

Comment: Graph discards and errors on all ports using SNMP and your preferred polling & graphing software.  Check if incidents of errors correspond to observations of bad behavior.  Use PingPlotter or similar to get a time-line of the observations you're currently doing in an adhoc manner with `ping`.

Comment: @JeffWheeler Thank you for pointing me at PingPlotter.  None of the switches are recording dropped or error packets.  I would like to see if there's a correlation to PAUSE frames.  We're working on getting an SNMP poller set up.

Comment: I think I miss-identified the mechanism I was thinking of as ARP caching, I was actually thinking of the switches MAC tables; the mechanisms the switch uses to identify which MAC(s) is / are attached to a given port.

Comment: The switch MAC address tables will not send that ICMP error for a host on a different network. That is from the router because the router is not getting an ARP response from the destination host. An unknown MAC destination simply makes the switch flood the frame to all interfaces.

Comment: `172.31.0.18: Destination host unreachable.` strongly looks like an ARP failure. Is that gateway the XS728T? Temporarily increase its ARP aging or set up static ARP to see if it changes anything. Check the switch's ARP cache when the error still comes up. Any DHCP snooping or MAC/IP bindings in place? The TTL indicates that there's another router involved - 62 = 64-2 - which one?

Comment: @Zac67  My office is in a different facility from the one experiencing the issue, though just down the road.  The other router involved is the one at my facility.  None of the symptoms we're seeing impact traffic strictly within this second site.

Comment: @Zac67  A colleague of mine did the test that you suggested previously, and found that no entry was present in the ARP cache.  Any idea hat would cause address resolution to be delayed to the order of several seconds?

Comment: @DominicHilsbos Doesn't a static entry stay put? You'll need to track the ARP request/replies down - one of them fails. Try ARPing the destination IP from another node in the subnet to see if it's the switch or the destination.

Comment: @Zac67  I'm sorry, i was referring to checking the ARP cache while the (obvious) issue was occurring.  We have not setup static ARP entries yet.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the switch configuration(s)?  Perhaps there is a clue there.

Comment: @RonTrunk  Not really... There are 340 physical ports, plus a dozen VLANs, and the LAGs, on the switches under discussion.  The configuration export from the XS724T alone is 20k worth of text.

Comment: @DominicHilsbos Also check whether the destination MAC stays in the switch's MAC table.

Comment: @DominicHilsbos  20K file?  Now I'm even more suspicious of the configuration.  You obviously have other features enabled besides LAGs.  It's going to come down to three things:  A faulty device, a bug, or a misconfiguration.  Maybe you could include a representative sample of the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn STP back on and leave it on.  It's conceivable that you have an intermittent loop.  Besides, it's good insurance.

If you have an ARP cache issue, you will only see it on the XS728T, as it's the only device doing routing.

See if your logs will show MAC address changes.  Something may be flapping between ports.

Comment: Ok, why / how would I be seeing an intermittent loop?

Comment: Perhaps one of your workstations is bridging intermittently.

Comment: An intermittent loop causes high broadcast rates and generally higher port utilization (when uninterrupted to a point that reasonable traffic fails).

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I participated in this question.

I believe I located 90% of our problem; we did indeed have a loop.  A member of IT had plugged in an additional cable between a switch and a wall port, thus generating a loop.

Since the new link was only gigabit, as compared to the LAGged 10G that is common for inter-switch connections in our network, the symptoms I expected to see weren't present.

Comment: You should accept your answer as correct so it won't keep popping up in the list looking for an answer.  Glad you solved it.

Comment: @RonTrunk I accepted your answer, is that not sufficient?